# A URL specified in a separate line in Java doesn't issue compile-time errors. Why?

Tags: java

Some days age, I mistakenly pasted a URL in my Java program in a hurry, I attempted to run that specific program and in my curiosity, it ran successfully with no warnings, no errors and no exceptions. The similar code is as shown below. I compiles and runs successfully.

```
final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {                    
        System.out.println ("A curiosity");
        https://localhost:8181/OnlineShoppingCartSystem-war/Restricted/Home
        System.out.println ("compiled Ok!");
    }
}
```

At the second line within the main() method, it should issue some compile-time errors but it works well and displays the respective messages on the console. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tokens `https:` gets interpreted as a label. And the `//` that follows starts a new-line comment. So, the posted code continues to be valid Java (if you notice the syntax coloring).

Answer (score 3):

Because `//` starts a comment and `https:` is interpreted as a label.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it looks like this to the compiler:

```
https: is a code label

//localhost:8181/OnlineShoppingCartSystem-war/Restricted/Home - is a comment
```

notice that the code highlighter works here as well as in your question.