# Add code labels when obfuscating code with proguard

Tags: android, proguard

As the answers to this question ( [A URL specified in a separate line in Java doesn't issue compile-time errors. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042626/a-url-specified-in-a-separate-line-in-java-doesnt-issue-compile-time-errors-wh) ) states you can add code labels on the code without having compilation errors.

Even more, using http:// will work as it will be considered a code label, and a comment.

So I was thinking...

**Can I add a number of random code labels** (including urls) to the code  **with proguard to make it even less readable**?

Of course I could add them by hand, but that would be a good solution, as it would polute the original code, and what I want it just on release compiled code.

I wanted to do this on Android apps, that's why I'm focusing on proguard (an out of the box solution for Android obfuscation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such labels won't affect the compiled code at all.

A label (be it "http:" or "somelabel:") doesn't show up in the compiled code, not even as debug information. It is only useful in combination with `break` statements.

A comment (be it "//www.example.com/path" or "//somecomment") doesn't get compiled in either. It is only useful to clarify the source code.

Since java bytecode doesn't represent labels or comments, ProGuard can't add them either. ProGuard also doesn't add unnecessary goto statements

Comment: That was correct information.. but not what i asked. I just asked if proguard can add dummy labels like that.

Comment: Since java bytecode doesn't represent labels or comments, ProGuard can't add them either. ProGuard also doesn't add unnecessary goto statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could check AspectJ which allows to create custom modifications of the byte code during build.
However I would not do that. Have you checked if java decompilers show your URLs?
You better optimize your obfuscation such that there is as little as possible in clear text.

Comment: You're right. It would probably indent the code so it would matter much. It was just for the fun anyway :-)